# posting on wordpress using c# library

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress

I am working with PHP and recently started to learn C# so know basic stuff, I used to post on my wordpress blog with MetaWeblog and I found a library here which can be used to post on wordpress using c# but i am not exactly sure how I can use it. I have imported library in visual studio.

http://www.matlus.com/metaweblog-api-c-library/

Kindly if someone can explain and possible show an example code on how to post I will really appreciate. there is a list of methods on above link.

methods
http://www.matlus.com/content/uploads/2011/01/MatlusMetaWeblogClassDiagram.jpg

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post you refer to tries to implement MetaWeblog support on the server side, which is not what you are looking for I think.

Maybe you can start from this one,

http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2006/06/creating-a-basic-metaweblog-api-blogging-client-in-c/